# Solve equation for time dependent variable

Tags: matlab, variables, time, solver, symbolic-math

I am trying to obtain the derivative of an analytic control input for a mechanical system. My problem can be compressed to the following problem:

I have an equation including the time dependent variable `a` that must be solved for `da/dt`.

The above part in my code is my desired way of solving this problem. I doesn't work though, for I can't manage to get the `solve` function to solve for a time dependent variable. I can use the workaround below by first working with independent variables and substituting the actual time dependent ones after the solve call. Since I have a lot of variables (and vectors of variables etc.) I was wondering whether there is a more straight forward manner to do this without the need of substitutions.

```
syms a(t) b(t)
equation = a + 3*b == 7;
% a = solve(equation, a) % <- this line isn't working. solve finds no solution
% a_dot = diff(a);


% "work around" by extra substitution
syms at bt
equation = at + 3*bt == 7;
at = solve(equation, 'at');
a = subs(at, bt, b);
a_dot = diff(a);
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve a differential equation? If so, you should be using `dsolve`.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Basically I am trying to solve the equation for da/dt, in simplest way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your first case doesn't work because because `a` and `b` are of class `symfun` – effectively functions. Even though it may look simple to you, because `a` and `b` are not values, `solve` doesn't know the properties of these functions in order to apply basic rules of algebra (e.g., associative, distributive). For example, it doesn't know if `a(t)` returns a real or complex value, whether the function may be single- or multi-valued at some `t`, whether the function returns a scalar or vector or matrix, etc. Of course if you explicitly define `a` and `b` then `solve` may work fine, but you'll need to solve for the variables in the functions not `a` and `b` themselves.

In your second case, `solve` assumes that `at` and `bt` are scalar algebraic variables. This is not a "workaround" but rather how to do what you want. Sorry if this seems unsatisfying. The only change I'd make is that you don't need to use a string for the variable name that you're solving for (some of the lines could be combined if you wanted too):

```
syms at bt b(t)
equation = at + 3*bt == 7;
at = solve(equation, at);
a = subs(at, bt, b);
a_dot = diff(a);
```

Note, in the future "this line isn't working. solve finds no solution" is not helpful. You should post the full error/warning message so that everyone knows exactly what you are seeing and can confirm that they get the same.

Comment: @Tano: Did I answer your question? Is it clear why the first case doesn't work? If this was helpful, please accept the answer. Thank you.